# How can I solve this complex Log equation?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

|Log z| = Re (Log z)

z is complex

Log z denotes the principle value of log z. -pi< Arg z< pi. Step by step solution please. I'll need to sketch it as well.

Comment: One should ask "step by step" hints if needed, don't ask for step by step solutions. It gives the impression that somebody else has to do your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|\log z| = \Re (\log z)
$

Let
$z = re^{it}
$.
$\log z
=\log(r)+it
$,
so
$|\log z|
=\sqrt{\log^2(r)+t^2}
$
and
$\Re (\log z)
=\log r
$.

If
$\log r
\ge 0
$,
then
$t = 0$
so $z$ must be real.

If
$\log r
\lt 0
$,
letting
$s = -\log r$,
and choosing the
negative square root,
$s
=\sqrt{s^2+t^2}
$,
and this implies that
$t = 0$.

Therefore,
the only solutions
are real $z$.